# Cannot register custom ELResolver

Tags: java, jsp

I want to use a custom EL resolver to escape XSS as described here:
http://pukkaone.github.io/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html

I added

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.github.pukkaone.jsp.EscapeXmlELResolverListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

to my web.xml which is version="3.0"

When I start up my app using the tomcat7-maven-plugin: mvn tomcat7:run
I get the following error

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.github.pukkaone.jsp.EscapeXmlELResolverListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.pukkaone.jsp.EscapeXmlELResolverListener.contextInitialized(EscapeXmlELResolverListener.java:37)
```

where `JspFactory.getDefaultFactory()` is returning null.

Related issues suggest that the issue is conflicting servlet/jsp jars but mine are defined as provided

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

I have also confirmed with `dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` that there are no stray dependencies on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

please can you check the dependency for servlet-api? artifactid should be servlet-api instead of javax.servlet-api

Comment: As stated above I am using servlet version 3.0 which corresponds to the newer javax.servlet-api artifacts.